# American Companies against Russia

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, economy, armed-conflict, ukraine

One of the things that happened with the Ukraine-Russia war was the exodus of American companies from Russia. Standard oil of New Jersey kept supplying Hitler oil till the very end during his Russian invasion , apparently because it was in US's favor at the time to do so. Now, it is in their favor if they leave Russia. Wouldn't countries become wary of American companies given that they are simply an extension of US foreign policy..or shall I say *Shouldn't* countries become wary?

Comment: If the US government cares enough, all companies in the west who want to not be hauled in by the FBI tend to comply, see the Iran sanctions.

Comment: WW2 was actually quite a while ago. Is there a reason to assume anyone's foreign policy may not change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are over-simplifying the WWII example. Germany prior to WWII was not *free*, the party was coercing companies while industrialists were lobbying the party. A foreign-owned company that was not seized would be heavily regulated.

So to the core of your question, **it depends**. The ability of the US to coerce the rest of the world is limited when nobody else agrees, it is stronger when the rest of "the West" agrees with them. Compare the effectiveness of the [US embargo against Cuba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_embargo_against_Cuba), where few are joining the Americans, with the effectiveness of the [US sanctions on Iran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_sanctions_against_Iran), where the EU was not as extreme as the US, and now Russia.

Certain countries would hesitate to put their money into American banks. They would then look for alternatives. London? Zurich? The Bahamas? Qatar? Going to London is not much better than New York. Zurich is a little more independent, but still part of the West. Other financial places risk coming onto money-laundering black lists, themselves.

Answer (score 1):

All other countries planning actions highly comparable to the Ukraine invasion in the future should become extremely wary indeed. "Highly comparable" I mean how it would look from the view point of USA they are highly comparable. But such countries  probably do not make the majority in the world so nobody cares. Most live in peace with they neighbours pretty well and do not even think to "denazify" them. Many are just too small.